# Finding roots of complicated expression involving DawsonF

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have this rather complicated equation, which I am trying to solve with Mathematica:

$$ \sqrt{A q} \left(A c e^{-\frac{z (A z+2 p)}{q}}+1\right)-2 p F\left(\frac{p+A z}{\sqrt{A q}}\right) =0, $$

where $F(z)$ is [`DawsonF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DawsonF.html), $A, q, p >0$ are constants, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to solve for $z$.

When I use `Solve`, it returns *"This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."*

```
Solve[(1 + A c E^(-((z (2 p + A z))/q))) Sqrt[A q] - 
 2 p DawsonF[(p + A z)/Sqrt[A q]] == 0, z]
```

How can I approach finding solutions?

Comment: Can you give an example of numerical values for the parameters $A,q,p$? You can use `FindRoot` with these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying the parameters a bit:

- Set $x=\frac{p+A z}{\sqrt{A q}}$ to simplify the argument of the Dawson function to $F(x)$, and
- set $s=\frac{p}{\sqrt{A q}}$ and $t=A c e^{s^2}$ to simplify a bit more.

Inverting these substitutions:

```
Solve[{x == (p + A z)/Sqrt[A q],
       s == p/Sqrt[A q], 
       t == A c E^s^2}, {z, p, c}] // FullSimplify
(*    {{z -> (q (-s + x))/Sqrt[A q],
        p -> Sqrt[A q] s,
        c -> (E^-s^2 t)/A}}    *)
```

With these replacements, the equation becomes a bit simpler and depends only on two parameters $s,t$ instead of four parameters $A,c,q,p$:

```
(1 + A c E^(-((z (2 p + A z))/q))) Sqrt[A q] - 2 p DawsonF[(p + A z)/Sqrt[A q]] == 0 /.
{z -> (q (-s + x))/Sqrt[A q], p -> Sqrt[A q] s, c -> (E^-s^2 t)/A} // FullSimplify
(*    E^-x^2 Sqrt[A q] (E^x^2 + t - Sqrt[π] s Erfi[x]) == 0    *)
```

So now we can try to solve the simplified equation

$$
1+t e^{-x^2} -2s F(x)=0
$$

where I have converted the simplified result back to a Dawson function.

We solve it numerically:

```
xsol[s_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  NSolveValues[1 + t E^(-x^2) - 2 s DawsonF[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

Example:

```
xsol[2.7, 0.2]
(*    {0.228094, 2.90476}    *)
```

Make a solver to get $z(A,c,p,q)$ instead of $x(s,t)$:

```
zsol[A_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] :=
  (Sqrt[A q] # - p)/A & /@ xsol[p/Sqrt[A q], A c E^(p^2/(A q))]
```

Try it out:

```
zsol[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
(*    {-2.12544, 0.693172}    *)
```